# Azure website Rest Api only accept GET, POST returns 403. Possibly CORS

Tags: azure, cors, azure-web-app-service

I am encounter a strange problem. I have a Asp.net Core WebApi project running under Azure App Service (Website). I am using DHC plug-in in Chrome. My service is also running with AAD.

I can request a GET method just fine (After login). However, when I request any POST, I got a 403 response. Looking around in the log, I can see this

> 2016-07-28T08:14:26  PID[x] Verbose     Received request: POST https://blahblah.azurewebsites.net/api/build/beep/
>
> 2016-07-28T08:14:26  PID[x] Verbose     Found 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site 'blah.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 856.
>
> 2016-07-28T08:14:26  PID[x] Information Sending response: 403.60 Forbidden
>
> 2016-07-28T08:14:26  PID[x] Warning     Cross-site request forgery detected for user 'blah@blahblah.com' from referer ''!

I am using Asp.net Core 1.0. I have CORS enable in my code (AllOrigin AllHeader), as well as the CORS in Azure website has an entry for '*', which supposed to accept every origin. The log stream seems like it does not even hit my website, but something in Azure blocks the request.

Any help?

Edit:
A successful GET method

> 2016-07-28T20:24:35  PID[22880] Verbose     Received request: GET https://blah.azurewebsites.net/api/build/beep/
>
> 2016-07-28T20:24:35  PID[22880] Verbose     Found 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site 'blah.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 876.
>
> 2016-07-28T20:24:36  PID[22880] Verbose     Authenticated blah@blah.com successfully using 'Session Cookie' authentication.

Comment: Looks like your JavaScript client is being blocked by the Authentication / Authorization module's CSRF protection, which currently doesn't know about the CORS configuration (it probably should). In your scenario, how did your end user get logged-in originally?

Comment: I use chrome to auth with AAD and my corporate credential. After logging in, Azure lets GET request go thru just fine. I edited my post to also include a log for a successful GET request.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm experiencing the same thing, but Chrome has a bug that prevents the user-agent from being set.

Comment: In case some get a similar issue, I documented a step-by-step minimalist fix, that does not rely on the User-Agent.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72511326/azure-blocks-post-requests-from-user-agent-mozilla-5-0-to-app-service/72522921#72522921

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your JavaScript client is being blocked by the Authentication / Authorization module's CSRF protection, which currently doesn't know about the CORS configuration (it probably should - I'll look into this).

The simplest way to work around this is to add a custom **User-Agent** HTTP header in your client settings. One of the things our built-in CSRF protection looks for is whether the client is a browser. Pretty much all major browsers use "Mozilla/..." as the user-agent string. Change this to something else to make it clear that you're not a browser and your POST request will go through successfully.

Comment: I can confirm this is the right answer. Settings User-Agent to something else, such as 'foo' works. Thanks Chris

Comment: See also here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1602

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove:

Origin: https://....

changing User-Agent didn't work