# How to work with XSRF protection for Azure Web application

Tags: java, angularjs, azure, csrf

I am developing a web application using MS Azure. The backend is a JAVA/Spring application, and the front is a Javascript/Angular development, but I don't think it is relevant. 
My problem is that authenticated POST requests from my front are blocked by azure XSRF protection, and I cannot find any information about it. Just to make it clear, non authenticated request are passing through without problems, as well as authenticated GET request. However any authenticated POST will generate a log similar to:

```
2017-02-23T22:44:46  PID[2668] Verbose Received request: POST https://immosearchapi.azurewebsites.net/profile

2017-02-23T22:44:46  PID[2668] Verbose Found 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site 'immosearchapi.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 556.

2017-02-23T22:44:46  PID[2668] Information Sending response: 403.60 Forbidden

2017-02-23T22:44:46  PID[2668] Warning Cross-site request forgery detected for user 'contact@arimaz.com' from referer 'immosearchweb.azurewebsites.net'!
```

I have found this reply:
    [Azure website Rest Api only accept GET, POST returns 403. Possibly CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630765/azure-website-rest-api-only-accept-get-post-returns-403-possibly-cors)

Which is actually a possible workaround as changing the Use-Agent header effectively disables XSRF protection for this request.

BUT... changing the User-Agent is not possible on Chrome, which is not acceptable in my case.

So is there a way to completely disable XSRF for an Azure backend (as security is not really a concern at this stage)?

Or where could I find documentation about the expected cookies and or headers for the request to be accepted?

thank you in advance...

**Update:**
This is not really an answer to my own question, but as an update, my workaround for this issue has been to change the project architecture to a single server approach. I updated my Spring app to serve the front end as well as the Rest API to avoid CORS and XSRF issues with Azure. I have never been able to make ADAL work, and it seems to be supporting MS accounts only, which is not a solution for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you had enabled the `Authentication / Authorization` feature for your web application on Azure WebApp. So if you want to do the cross-site request, there are two ways which might be helpful for you.

1. Using `Adal.js` or `Adal-Angular` for your current scenario, please follow the README content of [`ADAL for JS`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) to change your code. And there is a [blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/) which introduce for adal js library.
2. Just per my experience, you can create a similar interface on `immosearchweb.azurewebsites.net` for angular request call and pass the request parameter & body using HttpClient in Java to call the interface on `immosearchapi.azurewebsites.net`. It seems to be simple.

Comment: Authentication is obviously the root cause of the problem. I managed to get ADAL for js working, but I cannot figure out how to issue an authenticated request to my backend API (Azure authentication is **realy** confusing). So basically it doesn't solve my problem, I still got 403 response. By any chance, would you have any information about option 2. Trying to generate authenticated requests without ADAL?