# HTTP Error 403.60 - Forbidden When posting form on azure web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis

I'm in the process of moving an on premise app to azure web app.  When i try to submit a form using post on any action, the application returns an iis error message of HTTP Error 403.60 - Forbidden.  All the get requests are working correctly, this issue doesn't occur when running the application on a local IIS.

Can anyone suggest what to check? I have other azure web applications that submit posts and dont have this issue.

Comment: see if you have anonymous access enabled on portal or if you are using identity. If you have Application Insights set up see if you get anything logged in there.

Comment: authentication mode is windows, and i'm using Azure AD to authenticate

Comment: Share the code snippet what you have tried to configure authentication, Share if you are using On prem Azure Ad or other? Please post the details as much as you can.

Comment: Below is the setting in the webconfig, and I also have the app registration in azure to allow for Azure AD sign on
 
 
 <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>

Comment: 403.60 is Azure only (from threads like https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/issues/81). That's why you don't see this issue on IIS.

Comment: 403.60 means The request was rejected by the built-in CRSF protection rules. So you need to check whether CORS configuration has been set correctly. You could check whether the solution in this link would help.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630765/azure-website-rest-api-only-accept-get-post-returns-403-possibly-cors

Comment: Thanks @JokiesDing, i logged a call with MS, but soon after that the issue resolved it's self.  No changes were made to the app  between the issue being identified and logged,  so i'm waiting to see if anything changed on the backend

Comment: MS have not been able to resolve it yet but I have found that some browser work whilst others don't

Edge  (Works)
IE 11 (works)
Edge Canary (HTTP Error 403.60 - Forbidden)
Chrome (HTTP Error 403.60 - Forbidden)
Vivaldi (HTTP Error 403.60 - Forbidden)