# Azure blocks POST requests from User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 to App Service

Tags: javascript, azure, http, security, web

I have an **Azure App Service** with a mandatory Authentication based on the Azure Active Directory. It is serving an API server and a webapp calling the server.

All the GET work perfectly, however the POST all get rejected with
`403 Forbidden`.
The Cookies are properly set to pass the authentication check.

Oddly enough, when I replayed the POST with **Postman**, they succeeded.
I could narrow down the difference that lead to rejection:

> Whenever the `User-Agent` header is `Mozilla/5.0`

Why is there such a mechanism in Azure ? How to deactivate it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure website Rest Api only accept GET, POST returns 403. Possibly CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630765/azure-website-rest-api-only-accept-get-post-returns-403-possibly-cors)

Comment: Not exactly, but thanks to the resources linked I could elaborate the accurate minimal working solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging in the suggestion, I could verify that it was not a CORS issue neither precisely a User-Agent to change.

Actually Chrome browser does not support User-Agent update as of 2022-06-06, so this option cannot be chosen.

The solution idea came from https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1602#issuecomment-309532954

And to focus on the fix, in `App Service` / `Authentication`:

1. Authentication settings (Edit)
2. Allowed external redirect URLs: Add `https://{name}.azurewebsites.net`

[image: step-by-step azure setting]

After this, POST requests worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a non-cross-origin scenario, but for me [Benjam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72522921/472575) did not work as (it turned out later) the browser sent neither origin (actually `null` was sent) nor referrer header - therefore there was nothing to match with the redirect URLs.

I recommend checking out and evaluating all the [CSRF rules](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1602#issuecomment-309511229) laid out in the thread mentioned in Benjam's answer.

In my case, the issue was a [`Referrer-Policy: no-referrer` setting](https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/latest/nwebsec/Configuring-referrerpolicy.html) that made the browser omit the referrer header. After relaxing the policy, POST requests got through.